# MariaDB on duplicate key update

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

if the key is duplicated, i want to make qty = (current qty)+(new qty)

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

in Mariadb doc, there is only assigning column value case.

```
CREATE TABLE Cart(
    buyer varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    productid int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    qty int(11) NOT NULL
);

$addCart_sql = "INSERT INTO Cart (buyer, productid, qty) 
                VALUES ('$buyer', $productid, $qty)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = VALUES(qty + $qty)";
```

i tried

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = VALUES(qty) + VALUES($qty);
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = VALUES(qty) + $qty;
```

but all cases return error

how can i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = VALUES(qty) + qty
```